# Why some code statements appears one-symbol-per-row in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, code-formatting

Sometimes when I'm viewing existing code, some fragments appear very odd: one symbol per row with alignment to left. For example, I have opened some code of some framework and I saw that weird formatting in some fragments. I have checked that those lines do not contain tabs or spaces. So, what might be a cause? I would be cool to hear from you that you have experienced that too, so please mark a question or post to comments.

UPDATE: here's the screen:[image]

Comment: A screenshot or two would be great. I have a hard time understanding what you're seeing.

Comment: I've seen this happen often when copy/pasting code.

Comment: Yes, but it's strange when it happens with an existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug that you need to [report to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).